# How to load local HTML pages in WebBrowser control in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, c#-2.0

I have number of local HTML pages. I want to display these local HTML pages in Web browser control. When I add new page it should get append to previous page.

Here is the sample code for the setting Url

```
for( int i=0; i<=filecount; i++)
    web-browser.Url = new Uri(filepath[i]);
```

But during run time its showing the File Download pop up and web browser is empty.

Comment: What is in your filepath[i] variable? If it are local files then append "file://" in front of them. Also shouldn't you use the web-browser.Navigate(<url>) function?

Answer (score 23):

You could load a single page as

```
FileStream source = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
webBrowser1.DocumentStream = source;
```

or even like

```
string html = File.ReadAllText(filepath);
webBrowser1.DocumentText = html;
```

But if you have images, css or js in the relative paths, use

```
Uri uri = new Uri(filepath);
webBrowser1.Navigate(uri);
```

Comment: Thanks Mobel. Its working now.But its not able to show the images .

Comment: If you want to load an html with related images use the Navigate method like  var uri = new Uri(filepath);
             webBrowser1.Navigate(uri);

Comment: If you are looking for something like, those html files as a part of your solution instead of some folder, you can those html and related files to your  project as content and in properties change to "copy to output directory" : copy always option. and load it like string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            var url = new Uri(String.Format("file:///{0}/{1}", curDir, "test.html"));
            webBrowser1.Navigate(url);

Comment: Great its working for HTML files. But now i have new issue.Is it possible to load local XHTML pages in the webbrowser control?

Comment: Any idea about loading enormous xml file in the web browser .. My xml file size is 65 gb

Answer (score 0):

```
webrowser.Navigate(filepath[i]);
```

something like that i remember... ;)

Answer (score -1):

I tried:

```
FileStream source = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
webBrowser1.DocumentStream = source;
```

I had to add this also:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentStream.Close();
```

Comment: this is not an answer to this question'