# System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser Navigate to html-file on disk

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-lightswitch

I feel really stupid but i cant figure this one out.

This works flawless;

```
((System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser)e.Control).Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
```

But when i try to navigate to a file on disk it fails

```
string path =@"D:\dev\MySite.html";

((System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser)e.Control).Navigate(new Uri(path));
```

I guess i cant use Uri but what else should i use to navigate to a file on disk?

full code;

```
    private void webControlAvailable(object sender, ControlAvailableEventArgs e)
    {

         string path =@"D:\dev\MySite.html";

        ((System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser)e.Control).Navigate(new Uri(path));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser` to navigate to local files is quite a tough one. You can try this one, though:

```
string path =@"file://127.0.0.1/D$/dev/MySite.html";
((System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser)e.Control).Navigate(new Uri(path));
```

If you have `JavaScript` one your site it might be a little ugly and fail.

You can also use a `System.IO.Stream` to navigate, using `WebBrwoser.NavigateToStream()`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560639/how-to-load-local-html-pages-in-webbrowser-control-in-c-sharp) thread on SO and the [official](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostream.aspx) documentation.

Comment: is it FileStream source = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); that one you had in mind toghter with NavigateToStream?

Comment: Yes, for example. Open the `System.IO.Stream` in the manner you like or can handle and use this stream for the `NavigateToStream()`-method

Comment: NavigateToStream is not a valid method :/ Damn this was harder then i thought. For a bit of context im writing code inside a lightswitchapplication.

Comment: Im sorry about that i didnt think i did matter, i should still have accsess to the full .net-framwork right? I updated the post with the full code.

Comment: Not necessarily... What does MSDN say?

Comment: Give me the link, please, I'll have a look at it

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/081faa3e-a2fa-4e79-8720-a5ac2096e764/ I didnt find the orignial, but here it is stated that it supports ASP.NET 4.0 but thats maybe not the same

Comment: No, it's not the same... What are you actually up to??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26924/discussion-between-tim-and-bash-d)