# Show an HTML file of my Project in WebBrowser control at run-time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I want to show a local html file which exists in my project:

[image: Solution Explorer]

The calling file is the `HelpFile.cs` and in that the form contains the `WebBrowser` control.

The address I'm trying to reach is:

```
C:\Users\Keith\Desktop\Lingerie\Corset\Corset\Bra.html
```

The file is being called from:

[image: Webbrowser Properties]

The result is the dreaded page can't be displayed.

What I would like to do is be able to call the file as a relative html page. At a later stage, I would like to be able to call different help files.

Is this the best way to proceed or have I made a fundamental error and gone down the wrong path?

Any constructive help would be appreciated.

Comment: After you run the program in users machine, the files will not be in `C:\Users\Keith\Desktop\Lingerie\Corset\Corset\Bra.html`.  Also it's enough to navigate to the address simply using `C:\Users\Keith\Desktop\Lingerie\Corset\Corset\Bra.html`

Comment: I would suggest embedding the files as part of the project's resources, that way you can run the program on any machine without having to worry whether or not the .html files are on the user's c:\ drive. I would also not hard code the path in the designer view properties. Assign the files to the webbrowser with any of the options from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560639/how-to-load-local-html-pages-in-webbrowser-control-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file which exists in your project, lives in a specific location in your machine. But after you distribute the program and run it on user's machine, the file will not exists in the target machine.

You may want to distribute the file or add it as resource. To solve the problem you can use either of the following solutions:

- You can copy the file to output directory at build time
- You can add the file to a resource file like `Resources.resx`
- You can make the file as an embedded resource

Then to show the file, you can use the following methods:

- Get the file path and call the [`Navigate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigate?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) method or assign it to [`Url`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.url?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property
- Get the resource content and assign it to [`DocumentText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property
- Get the resource stream and assign it to [`DocumentStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentstream?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property

### Copy the file to Output Directory

To copy the file to output directory at build time:

- Solution explorer → See properties of your file
- Set *Build Action* to *Content*.
- Set *Copy to Output Directory* to *Copy always*.

Then the file will be copied to your output directory and you can use it this way:

```
var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "test.html");
this.webBrowser1.Navigate(path);
```

Please note, if the file is located under a folder in your project, for example under `MyFolder`, then it will be copied into a folder with the same name in the output directory of the application:

```
var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "MyFolder", "test.html");
this.webBrowser1.Navigate(path);
```

### Add the file to a resx resource file like Resources.Resx

You can add the file to resource file of the project. This way it will be distributed in a resource assembly and you don't need to copy the file to output directory. To do so:

- Solution explorer → Your project → *Properties* folder → open *Resources.Resx* file
- From toolbar of the designer → *Add existing file* → Add the html file.

Then the content of the file will be available through a string property of the `Resources`. The property name will be same as the file name, for example if the file name is `test.html`, the property name will be `test` and You can use it this way:

```
this.webBrowser1.DocumentText = Properties.Resources.test;
```

Please note, for this solution the file doesn't need to be distributed by your project and it will be part of the resource file. However it will be part of your project file.

### Make the file as an embedded resource

You can make the file as an embedded resource. This way it will be distributed in a resource assembly and you don't need to copy the file to output directory. To do so:

- Solution explorer → See properties of your file
- Set *Build Action* to *Embedded Resource*.
- Set *Copy to Output Directory* to *Do not copy*.

Then to use, you need to get the file content from embedded resources. Assuming the file name is "test.html":

```
var fileName = "test.html";
var name = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()
    .Where(x => x.EndsWith(fileName)).First();
webBrowser1.DocumentStream = 
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(name);
```

Please note, if you have the file inside a folder like `MyFolder` in the project, then the filename in above example will be "MyFolder.test.html".